# Excel User-defined function name clashes with cell name

Tags: excel, add-in

Following a recent upgrade to Excel 2010 (from Excel 2003) we noticed an issue with a function call from one of our XLA add-ins. 
The function is showing **#REF!** in Excel 2010 but worked in Excel 2003, I eventually traced this to a naming problem. The function name is **PEN60(...)** but in Excel 2010 **PEN60** is a valid cell reference so rather than a calculated value I get the **#REF!**.

The fully qualified function name (i.e. with the full path to the add-in) works as expected.

Any idea how this can be fixed, bar renaming the function?

Comment: Just curious - Why not rename the function? You could simply change it to `_PEN60` or something similar and then do a large `Find/Replace` through your entire workbook? The fact of the matter is that, suppose in Excel 2003 you had a function named `A1()`... You'd want that error to occur since call A1 is almost always used... In this case, you're still referring to a range address, it's just a more obscure location in the sheet...

Comment: the other way would be to change to **R1C1** style references, so that PEN60 is no longer a valid reference

Comment: John, this add-in has been in use by the company for a very long time so there are - quite literally - tens of thousands of spreadsheets which expect this function name. 
Sean, for a similar reason - not to mention user opposition - I don't think this is a way forward. Does work though and I hadn't thought of it so thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to automate the renaming as efficiently as possible:
- Duplicate the function with another name (eg NewPEN60)
- add a routine to your XLA that is triggered whenever a workbook is opened (Application event) that looks in all the worksheets of the newly opened workbook using SpecialCells select errors for #Ref, checks if the formula uses PEN60 and replaces it with Newpen60 if it does.

Comment: Charles (and John Bustos in comment above), Yes I'm inclined to think this is the best solution - Grr! More pain :-(